# How to bind datatable at specific event

Tags: c#

How to bind datatable at specific events, like when record is deleted or added to the database?

For example:

```
if(CHANGE IN DATABASE[TABLE])
{
     (bind data table)
}
else
{
     (display old bound data table)
}
```

Comment: You could use [SqlDependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency)

Comment: HOW CAN I MAKE DATABALE STATIC